# Print CString to Messagebox

Tags: visual-c++

How to correctly print a CString to messagebox? There is nothing appear..

```
CString testing;
testing = ExecuteExternalProgram();

MessageBox(NULL, testing, L"test", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try AfxMessageBox.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as6se7cb(v=vs.71).aspx

lpszText
Points to a CString object or null-terminated string containing the message to be displayed in the message box.

or do:

MessageBox(NULL, testing.GetBuffer(), L"test", MB_OK);

Comment: The error says: Error 2 error C3861: 'AfxMessageBox': identifier not found

Comment: I included the afxwin.h. But this error appear: Error 1 fatal error C1189: #error :  WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>

Comment: Alright I see what you did there. remove afxwin.h and do: MessageBox(NULL, testing.GetBuffer(), L"test", MB_OK);